# Using a transitive verb at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, transitive-verbs, sentence-ends

Is it ever appropriate to use a transitive verb at the end of a sentence? Specifically, the sentence that I'm considering is one that ends in "... [someone] will update [a thing] as changes in [other things] necessitate".

I know that it can be reworked, but I'm curious if the sentence above is valid from a grammar standpoint.

Comment: Yes, but more idiomatic would be: as changes to x **are needed**.or as changes require.

Comment: Oh, come on @Hot Licks, you know perfectly well that a sentence is one of the few things a preposition _can_ end.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Actually, in the US a number of sentences end with execution.

Comment: Yes, it's quite normal for a clause to end with a transitive verb. Very often the missing object is recoverable from some other expression located earlier in the clause. In your example the object is _understood_ as "updates".

Comment: @BillJ, awesome thank you for your help!